# What is the etymology or software principle behind "fuse" in Rust?

Tags: rust, terminology

I am running up against the word `fuse` in the Rust ecosystem:

- [`slog::Fuse`](https://docs.rs/slog/2.5.2/slog/struct.Fuse.html) to promote errors to panics.
- [`FutureExt::Fuse`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.fuse) "Fuse a future such that poll will never again be called once it has completed."

I'm aware of Linux's FUSE, a userspace filesystem.  A fuse is also an electrical component that goes into open circuit state when too much current goes through the fuse.  In hardware "fusing" describes baking configuration into the silicon by (historically) blowing circuits in the silicon through over-current in specific wires of the silicon.

**What does "fuse" generally mean in Rust and what is its etymology?**

Comment: The first one is probably like the electrical sense - an error is like an overcurrent condition, and the "fuse" causes such a condition to permanently disable the device (panic the program).  I don't know enough about futures to guess at the second.  Note there's also the verb sense of fuse: to join two things together, as by melting.

Comment: True.  Forgot about the join meaning. I'm seeing it in many places throughout Rust, but documentation always seems to imply I already know something about what "fuse" means in the Rust context.

Comment: `FutureExt::Fuse` comes from [`Iterator::fuse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse), which again comes from the electrical meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The earliest use I could find of "fuse" in the Rust ecosystem is [`Iterator::fuse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse), which [was added to the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/8276) during the pre-1.0 days. The initial documentation for `Iterator::fuse` said:

```rust
/// Creates an iterator that yields `None` forever after the underlying
/// iterator yields `None`. Random-access iterator behavior is not
/// affected, only single and double-ended iterator behavior.
```

There was also a function on the returned iterator that has since been removed:

```rust
impl<T> Fuse<T> {
    /// Resets the fuse such that the next call to .next() or .next_back() will
    /// call the underlying iterator again even if it prevously returned None.
    #[inline]
    fn reset_fuse(&mut self) {
        self.done = false
    }
}
```

This indicates that `Fuse` is an analogy to [a resettable electric fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse). The name is entirely unrelated to the FUSE filesystem.

[`FutureExt::Fuse`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.fuse) is basically the `Future` equivalent to `Iterator::Fuse`. Support for `Future`s in Rust came far after support for `Iterator`s.

The common thread here is that a `fuse` function takes **"a thing that produces things, and can stop"**, and makes it so it doesn't produce things after it stops.

`slog::Fuse` is not a typical use of the word "fuse": that use might be referencing the fuse of a bomb, which is easily ignited (it makes errors easily ignite/panic the program). You can *kinda* fit it onto the earlier definition I made if you think of it as "a thing produces a stream of successes/failures, and `fuse` takes a failure and makes it so it doesn't produce anything more after a failure". [The commit that added it](https://github.com/slog-rs/slog/commit/e44b22f2f4321fee452aa9bd95658afbe06dd508) doesn't provide any hints as to the meaning.